# Visual Studio 2008 crashes and has to be restarted when I start the debugger

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

My Visual Studio crashes each time I try to debug my ASP.net application.

I've been working on this application for months and only now has this issue come up.  I've tried rebooting to no avail.

When I press F5, Visual Studio immediately freezes up and displays no error message.  I also get the exact same behavior when I use the "Attach to Process" option to start the debugger.

The problem happens only with a particular application I'm working on.  If I create a new project, I can debug that project, but as soon as I open up my original project, it's the same story all over again.

Also, I should point out that the "development server" icons appear in the System tray and do not disappear after the frozen Visual Studio 2008 is terminated.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Have you tried repairing or uninstalling/reinstalling VS2008?

Comment: That's the next thing on my list.  I might my sysadmin to install VS2K10 and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: Do you have admin privileges?  I had some strange problems with VS debugging with Win7 UAC enabled.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your symbol cache?  The first thing the debugger does is load symbols and a corrupt symbol file might be the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the sysadmin re-install VS2k8 for me.  That fixed the problem.

For some odd reason, the *uninstall* process took a very long time that surprised even the sysadmin who uninstalled and reinstalled it for me.  I wonder if that could have anything to do with the problem.

Anyhow, the reinstall got me up and running again.